# Script for TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me write a Transact-SQL script.

There is a table with conditional columns **PK_ID** (*Number*), **FK_ID** (*Number*) and **SEQ** (*Number*):

- PK_ID is always unique.
- Several PK_IDs can be assigned to one FK_ID.
- SEQ is the sequence number for the PK_ID, in order of priority assignment to the FK_ID.

I just can’t write a script that would change the entries in SEQ from 1 to the sequence number of the last FK_ID entry in the PK_ID context, provided that initially all **SEQ = 1**.

What is now (*Example*):

```
| PK_ID|  FK_ID | SEQ |
| ---- | ------ |  -  |
| 121  | 18821  |  1  |
| 358  | 18821  |  1  |
| 611  | 18821  |  1  |
| 7251 | 23357  |  1  |
| 95   | 23357  |  1  |
| 922  | 15511  |  1  |
| 1    | 53810  |  1  |
| 777  | 53810  |  1  |
| 953  | 53810  |  1  |
| 120  | 53810  |  1  |
```

Result:

```
| PK_ID|  FK_ID | SEQ |
| ---- | ------ |  -  |
| 121  | 18821  |  1  |
| 358  | 18821  |  2  |
| 611  | 18821  |  3  |
| 7251 | 23357  |  1  |
| 95   | 23357  |  2  |
| 922  | 15511  |  1  |
| 1    | 53810  |  1  |
| 777  | 53810  |  2  |
| 953  | 53810  |  3  |
| 120  | 53810  |  4  |
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question. Your attempt would go a long way to helping us understand what you want

Comment: Ok thanks, @Charlieface. I will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update your table.

Note: The window functions are well worth your time getting comfortable with.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i6RbwaFn)**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NewSEQ  = row_number() over (partition by FK_ID order by PK_ID)
 From YourTable
)
Update cte set SEQ=NewSEQ
 Where SEQ<>NewSEQ
```

**Results**

[image]